# Change debugging target device (emulator/hardware)?

Tags: android

I know this can be done but can't find the place to swap target debugging devices. I'm using now the emulator but want to switch to device and viceversa. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like this..

**Right Click** ON PROJECT--->Run As---->Run Configurations.. there in **Target** tab select Manual.. now Click **Run** then you will be showed with a list of emulators and connected devices.. from which you can choose..

Answer (score 3):

set the target device in Run Configuration

Answer (score 2):

If you launched emulator and connected device also, then every time while launching application,it will ask to select target device(only if there are more than one target device available). You can select the target device which you like.

Comment: I was asked first time wich device to use when I connected my device and ran the application. It is not letting me change the target device anymore after this first time.

Comment: if there are more than one target devices then it will ask to select. Check the number of devices available using 'adb devices' or in eclipse DDMS.